# How To Decorate PullRequest in BitBucket (Cloud) Pipelines with SonarQube 7.9

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket, pull-request, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a private SonarQube 7.9 installation on EC2 in AWS. I have successfully integrated our BitBucket (cloud (ie, not server/stash)) Pipeline build to use the SonarQube instance. I would like to take the next step and use the information to decorate our PullRequests with the analysis results from SonarQube; however, it seems like it may not be possible. It seems SonarCloud nicely integrates with BitBucket. Meanwhile, SonarQube only perhaps integrates well with a BitBucket server repository?

The only BitBucket plugin for SonarQube is this: https://github.com/mibexsoftware/sonar-bitbucket-plugin and it explicitly states that it only works with SonarQube 7.7 or earlier.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my research so far, which supports your conclusion:

- PR decoration by Sonarqube does not support Bitbucket Cloud.
  https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/analysis/pull-request/ OR
  https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/pr-decoration/
- "Bitbucket Cloud plug-in for SonarQube"  only supports  <7.7, but our Sonarqube is 7.9.
- "Sonar for Bitbucket Cloud"  is only applicable to PUBLIC repository.

**UPDATE:**

As of SonarQubte 8.9LTS Developer edition or higher,
PR decoration to Bitbucket Cloud seems to be supported.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/bitbucket-cloud-integration/